# How do you find out if a mutex object already exists in Linux?

Tags: android, linux, windows, multithreading, porting

I'm currently attempting to port a Multithreading library written for WIN32 to Android/Linux and I seem to have run into a bit of a problem trying to map over a particular feature that WIN32 mutexes have.

From the documentation for Windows Mutex Objects:

> Threads in other processes can open a handle to an existing mutex
>   object by specifying the object name in a call to CreateMutex. If a
>   mutex object with that name already exists, GetLastError returns
>   ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS.

I was not able to find any info on something in the Linux man pages that is similar to what the Windows API offers.

The main reason for my asking this question is that the mutex creation code I'm porting over contains:

```
isCreator = !(::GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS);
```

where `isCreator` is a boolean data type.  (Not sure what it's used for , but I think its important).

edit:

```
mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
// attributes??

if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) != 0) {
 throw Nv_EXCEPTION(XCPT_ResourceAllocationFailure, GetLastError());
}
```

Comment: What are you using for mutexes on Linux?

Comment: ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS really isn't an "error" in a lot of cases; if it just means a prior thread already created it.  Looking at the snippet isCreator is set when you have in fact created the mutex for the first time.

Comment: @seand: The biggest issue is that Windows mutexes seem to be system-wide whereas pthread mutexes are per-process.

Comment: So there's no way to find out on Linux if a particular thread/process already created a mutex?  Is it because mutexes on Linux are unnamed?

Comment: It depends entirely on how you're implementing the mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your easiest analog to a named, interprocess mutex is probably a [named realtime semaphore](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_open.html) initialized to a value of one (1).  Try to `sem_open("/the_sem", O_CREAT|O_EXCL, mode, 1)`.  O_EXCL will fail with EEXIST if you aren't the first, and a subsequent `sem_open` with no flags ought to succeed if you aren't the first:

```
sem_t *sem;
int isCreator = 0;

if ((sem = sem_open("/the_sem", O_CREAT|O_EXCL, mode, 1)) != SEM_FAILED) {
  // We got here first
  isCreator = 1;
} else {
  if (errno != EEXIST) uh_oh_goodbye();

  // We're not first.  Try again
  sem = sem_open("/the_sem", 0);
  if (sem == SEM_FAILED) uh_oh_goodbye();
}
```

Note:  you *can* share pthread mutexes (and anonymous realtime semaphores, for that matter) between processes, if the synchronization object is initialized in shared memory.  POSIX shared memory realtime extensions permit [shared memory to be named](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html), too.  There's then a bit of a race between creating the shared memory and initializing the mutex, but in this case attempting to call `pthread_mutex_init()` should fail with EBUSY for all but the race winner.

Comment: I meant to ask the question for Android, but unfortunately it seems like named mutexes don't exist.  The solutions I've seen involve the use of System V Semaphores similar to your answer.  Unfortunately, Android did not include the header files containing those API calls so that's not going to work either.